# CatchableFatalError to submit an embed form to persist entities (Argument 1 passed must be an instance of Entity, instance ArrayCollection given)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, doctrine-orm

I have an **embed form** in my symfony project concerning to persist two entities: `Stockage.php` and `Equipements.php`.

The relation between these entites is a **ManyToOne**.

This is the code for `Stockage.php`:

```
class Stockage
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nameStockage", type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nameStockage;

    /**
     * @var Equipements
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Equipements", inversedBy="stockage", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="equipements_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $equipements;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->equipements = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nameStockage;
    }

    /* ... getters and setters for id and name  */

    /**
     * Set equipements
     *
     * @param \MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Equipements $equipements
     * @return Stockage
     */
    public function setEquipements(\MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Equipements $equipements)
    {
        $this->equipements[] = $equipements;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get equipements
     *
     * @return \MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Equipements
     */
    public function getEquipements()
    {
        return $this->equipements;
    }
}
```

This is the code for `Equipements.php`:
class Equipements

```
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nameEquipement", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nameEquipement;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Stockage", mappedBy="equipements", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $stockage;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->stockage = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nameEquipement;
    }

    /* ... getters and setters for id and nameEquipement */

    /**
     * Set stockage
     *
     * @param \MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Stockage $stockage
     *
     * @return Equipements
     */
    public function setStockage(\MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Stockage $stockage = null)
    {
        $this->stockage = $stockage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get stockage
     *
     * @return \MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Stockage
     */
    public function getStockage()
    {
        return $this->stockage;
    }

    public function addStockage(Stockage $stockage)
    {
        if (!$this->stockage->contains($stockage)) {
            $this->stockage->add($stockage);
        }
    }
}
```

When I add a Stockage element, I can add an Equipement element, so this is the embed form **StockageType.php**:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nameStockage')
        ->add('equipements', 'collection', array(
                                            'label' => false,
                                            'type' => new EquipementsType(),
                                            'allow_add' => true,
                                            'by_reference' => false,
                                            ))
    ;
}
     /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Stockage'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'mySpace_myBundle_stockage';
}
```

When I submit my form I have this **error**:

> Argument 1 passed to MySpace/MyBundle/Entity/Stockage::setEquipements
>   must be an instance of MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Equipements, instance
>   of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given, called in
>   C:\wamp\www\MyApp\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php
>   on line 410 and defined',
>   'C:\wamp\www\MyApp\src\MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Stockage.php',
>   '128', array('this' => object(Stockage))) in
>   src/MySpace/MyBundle/Entity/Stockage.php at line 128

The line **128** in `Stockage.php` is this one : `public function setEquipements(\MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Equipements $equipements)`

Someone could help? Symfony need to have a return of a collection right?

---

### **EDIT**

I have an entity `Equipements.php` who could belong to **either** a `Stockage.php` or a `Generator.php` but an equipement **can not be both**. 
[image]

So when I would like to add an equipement I need to add the particularities of Stockage too if the equipement is a stockage, or the particularities of generator if the equipement is a generator. That's why I had to embed the `EquipementType.php` (collection) in `StockageType.php` or `GeneratorType.php`.

**PS: *I put this question as resolved, follow @Jean comments to make sure have the right way t0 build your embed form: if you have a OneToOne relation follow this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-single-object), else follow how to build and return an embed form with a collection like @Jean suggested in his coments and in his answer.***

Comment: It's inconsistent.. If it's OneToOne, Equipments shouldn't be an ArrayCollection but a single Equipment. If it isn't like this, it should be a OneToMany relation

Comment: You have set relation `OneToOne`  for `equipements` and in form your are using `collection` type field which is wrong

Comment: sorry a rookie mistake: I have to change the OneToOne relation in ManyToOne in Stockage.php. I have updated my code with the relation. But when I submit my form I have the same error occured.

Comment: Its just as @Jean said. The difference between `OneToOne` and `ManyToOne` is an extra unique key. `collection` form type is used on the side where you expect to get a collection of objects - that would means in your FormType that is related to entity `Equipments` for property `stockage`. Not the other way around.

Comment: @french_dev did you change the getter and setter also?

Comment: @Jean yes the getter and setter are updated too.

Comment: Andariel I understand what @Jean suggested me and why It is inconsistent. In my database a stockage can have many equipements but an equipement could have just one stockage.See my image in my updated in order to understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix the `Equipements::setStockage()` method, like this:

```
/**
 * Set stockages
 *
 * @param ArrayCollection $stockage
 *
 * @return Equipements
 */
public function setStockages(ArrayCollection $stockage)
{
    $this->stockage = $stockage;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: in fact your answer is the good one if I have a collection, but as I can told you, I have a One(Stockage)ToOne(equipement). So I don't need a collection. I was wrong to create an embed form with a collection type. I change all in my code like I don't need a collection and all works well. Of course, your answer works weel for a collection, I have tested her just now. Thank you, you rock ! I follow this [link](http://code-cocktail.in/one-one-relationship-embedded-forms/) and this [one too](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-single-object)